# How to call external javascript function in angular 5?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

I have downloaded a theme from [this](http://demo.themewagon.com/preview/free-multi-page-html5-portfolio-template-free-download) link. I have to define script and CSS in index.html file.

index.html (body section)

```
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/js/main.85741bff.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/js/common.js"></script>
</body>
```

I have defind my function in common.js and call it from main.85741bff.js file.

common.js (function)

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
     masonryBuild();
     navbarToggleSidebar();
     navActivePage();
});
```

The issue is that I am able to call the function while page reloads but can't call the function while content load.

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any success ? If yes please answer, the below answer does not work for me.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use javascript in the Angular application.

Step 1. Create **demo.js** file in **assets/javascript** folder.

```
export function test1(){
    console.log('Calling test 1 function');
}
```

Step 2. Create **demo.d.ts** file in **assets/javascript** folder.

```
export declare function test1();
```

Step 3. Use it in your component

```
import { test1 } from '../assets/javascript/demo'; 
 @Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {
    console.log(test1());
  }
}
```

*Note: js and .d.ts file name should be same*

Comment: @Ameya No need to import js file in angular.json or .angular-cli.json file.  For the use of first time, you can try in app.component.ts only you need to take care about directory path of assets folder. further, any problem share demo program on stackblitz

Comment: It works !!!, It worked 4 me, my bad did not concentrate on import. Deleting my older comment

Comment: It doesn't work for me, it return an error saying `error TS2306: File '.../demo.d.ts' is not a module.` Did I missed something ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the order in which you load your JavaSciprt files. Try loading `common.js` before `main......js`. Your script tries to access a function from a file that hasn't been loaded yet. Try just switching those two lines of code:

```
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/js/common.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/js/main.85741bff.js">/script>
</body>
```

Comment: Can we see the content of those `js` files?

Comment: Which js file common.js or main.85741bff.js ?

Comment: @Milan Both of them

Comment: @Milan The three functions that are you trying to call aren't defined in `main.85.....js`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159233/discussion-between-vtodorov-and-milan).

Answer (score 0):

In Angular4, 5 project folder, there is .angular-cli.json file.

In file, you will see

```
"apps": [
  {
    "scripts": []
  }
]
```

push your external js file path in the array.

Comment: Yes, I have tried before but it's not working while content load. It's working fine with page reload. Thoughts?

Answer (score -1):

You can call these methods by window object-

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
      window['navbarToggleSidebar']();
      window['navActivePage']();
 });
```

Comment: It's working fine with page reload but not working with particular content load. Thoughts?