# How to Use External Javascript in TypeScript Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

---

I want to use jquery and easypiechart js file's functions in typescript.

It doesn't work this way.

How to define these script what i specified in code as typescript ?

---

### index.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import * as $ from "../../../../../assets/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js";
import { easyPieChart } from "../../../../../assets/plugins/easypiechart/jquery.easypiechart.min.js";

// these above 2 js files are defined in angular.json script section

@Component({
  selector: 'app-index',
  templateUrl: './index.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./index.component.scss']
})

export class IndexComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {

    //$(function(){
    //  $('.easypiechart').easyPieChart();
    //});

    // How to write this above script as typescript ?????????????????????

  }
}
```

Comment: This looks `dublicate` of this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47346559/how-to-call-external-java-script-function-in-angular-5

Comment: as pointed out it`s a duplicate also why would you use jquery in angular? any specific reason for that?

Comment: Don't use jquery in angular. Choose one framework or the other

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using external JS libraries in my angular 2 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41120754/using-external-js-libraries-in-my-angular-2-project)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the above question,it looks like **jquery.easypiechart.min.js**  is the one that you need to use in your angular application as **external js**.

1. Put the js under assets folder say **/assets/js/jquery.easypiechart.min.js**
2. Goto your projects **angular.json** file and under scripts node of architect node put as an entry in the array.

   "scripts": [
                     "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
                     **"./src/assets/js/jquery.easypiechart.min.js"** ]

Now you can refer the external js in any of your projects components

```
  declare var $: any;// referencing jQuery library
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-index',
      templateUrl: './index.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./index.component.scss']
    })

    export class IndexComponent implements OnInit {
      constructor() {}
      ngOnInit() {
      $(document).ready(function () {
          //accessing easypiechart.min.js.
          $('.easypiechart').easyPieChart();
         });
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have included them in the scripts or index.html, you don't have to import them to the .TS file again

Use `declare` instead and it should work
[What does 'declare' do in 'export declare class Actions'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35019987/what-does-declare-do-in-export-declare-class-actions)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting it in asset folder you should use it as `node_modules` dependency

For easy pie chart run this [npm i easy-pie-chart --save](https://www.npmjs.com/package/easy-pie-chart) & for jquery run [npm i jquery](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Normally you don't want to use jquery in Angular, because it usually implies to modify directly the DOM, which is a bad practice, but there is the way to do it: https://medium.com/all-is-web/angular-5-using-jquery-plugins-5edf4e642969

If you wanna plot a pie chart or other types of charts, you could use [ng2-charts](https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/) instead, it will allow you to use [charts.js](https://www.chartjs.org/) with Angular and Typescript.