# how do we call a typescript function in a html code (not in the same file )

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, grafana

I'm trying to do a plugin for Grafana, so I took the clock-panel (given by Grafana) as an example.

So my problem is that I'm trying to call a TypeScript function from the file clock_ctrl.ts in the html file options.html.

I have tried many ways:

1. ```
   <form [ngFormModel]="companyForm" (submit)="namefunction()">
     <button type="submit">Save</button>
   </form>
   ```

but it doesn't work

2. ```
   <script src="../clock_ctrl.ts"></script>
   <body onload ="namefunction();">  </body>
       <button type="submit">Save</button>
   ```

but I obtain the error

> GET http://localhost:3000/clock_ctrl.ts 404 (Not Found)

and I can't find a solution to my problem.

Comment: TypeScript is transpiled to javascript - you shouldn't ever try to reference the .ts file directly. You likely should be including a script reference to `clock_ctrl.js`.

Comment: thank u for your answer but do u mean I should write <script src="../clock_ctrl.js"></script>?
because I did it and I got the same error

Comment: I'm not familiar with Grafana nor how you have your solution structured so I'm not sure of the exact method you need to use to reference the javascript file, but it most definitely is not the .ts file that you want to reference.

Comment: what do you mean by how my solution is structured?

Comment: You may find this post helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47346559/how-to-call-external-javascript-function-in-angular-5

Comment: @Rania I mean that I don't know the folder structure of your solution nor your build/deploy process. If you are getting a 404 when using `<script src="../clock_ctrl.js"></script>` it either means your javascript file is located somewhere else or your build process is not transpiling your TypeScript to javascript.

Comment: and how can I know if my build process is not transpiling my TypeScript to javascript ?